# I'm trying to do a void function to calculate area of a circle

Tags: c++, function, constants, geometry, void

I'm trying to write a void function to calculate the area of a circle. Here's my code so far:

```
Circle::Circle()
{
}
Circle::Circle(double r):Shape (){
    SetRadius(r);
}
double Circle::GetRadius(void) const{
    return radius;
}
void Circle::SetRadius(double r){
    this->radius = r;
}
void Area(double r){
    double area = pi(r*r);
}

Circle::~Circle()
{
}
```

I cannot figure it out, but I'm trying to access the private const data member pi from my .h in my function and it will not allow it. I had it working the other day when I tried starting it and now it will not allow it. Any help would be great.

Comment: You need the include the issue you are getting, but the cause is that you are not multiplying the (r*r) by pi like so: `pi*(r*r)`

Comment: Maybe `pi * r * r`? You're trying to call `pi` as if it's a function.

Comment: it tells me pi is undefined. Do I need to put the const variable in my constructor?

Comment: @MattRothenberg: Did you defined `pi`? Where is it defined? How?

Comment: pi is defined in my .h file for the class as 

double const pi = 3.14159

Comment: Are you including the .h file in the file where you have Circle source code?

Comment: @JuanPablo I am including the .h

Comment: If `Area` returns nothing and `area` isn't a member of your class... What do you do with that value?

Comment: i'm going to output it to the user. i'm learning inheritance and pure virtual functions right now, i don't fully understand it, but my teacher asked us to right a class shape with a pure virtual function void Area() and to overwrite it in a circle class and then a rectangle class so I'm just trying to do what I think is required. I'm not sure if what I am doing is correct.

Comment: Aren't you allowed to `#include<cmath>` and use `M_PI` constant? Then you can `cout << "Area: " << M_PI * r * r << '\n';`

Comment: maybe you meant `void Circle::Area` , rather than defining a non-member function. And you could use the radius class member instead of having parameter `r`.

Comment: it was the scope resolution operator missing.Thank you

Comment: If `Area` is a member function you can use `radius` which is a member too and avoid passing `r`. BTW you don't need `this->` in `SetRadius`.

Comment: If you defined `pi` as `const pi = 3.14159` then how are you not getting a compile error from `pi(r*r)`? You have not posted your actual code.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
void Area(double r){
    double area = pi*(r*r);
}
```

You using a hand writing notation to express the Area formula in c++. 
pi(r*r) in c++ stands for a function call to pi function.

Comment: Macros are usually defined uppercase, not constants.

Comment: And although this seems to be what the OP asked for, that is an utterly useless function. It calculates the area in a local variable which is promptly destroyed on return. I can't imagine an `Area` function that doesn't return the area, or at least store it in a class member.

Comment: @Carey Gregory you are right, it's use less but it's what it's asked.

Comment: @milleniumbuq you are right. I made my mind a define was used, but it's clearly said is a private const